# functional style validation algorithm

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Imagine hierarchical path stored in ordered List and its validation

```
List<String> path = Lists.newArrayList("path","to","end");

Iterator<String> iterator = path.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (iterator.next() == null) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next() != null) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid path");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The algorithm is pretty straightforward.

Only leafs or nodes with all its descendant must be null.

Valid paths:

```
"path", "to", "end"
"path", "to", null
"path", null, null
null, null, null
```

Invalid paths:

```
"path", null, "end"
null, null, "end"
null, "to", "end"
null, "to", null
```

I am looking for way to rewrite it in a functional style.

Comment: I think you've got some typos in your "valid paths" which are making your question confusing. Did you mean to put quotes around `null` is those places?

Comment: @4castle thx, i fixed the typo

Comment: What's wrong with non-functional solution? You said it yourself - your imperative algorithm is straightforward and relatively simple (I would only remove a second nested while, since you don't need it). It will gain no benefir from functional rewrite, and most likely will gain only complexity (I'm almost sure that functional implementation would require a `Tuple` class, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 9, you could use

```
if(path.stream().dropWhile(Objects::nonNull).anyMatch(Objects::nonNull))
    throw new Exception("Invalid path");
```

The logic is simple, first, drop all non-`null` values until the encounter of a `null` value (if any), then, fail if any non-`null` value follows.

Since Java 8 lacks [the `dropWhile` operation](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-), we have to prepend an alternative operation, e.g. using the Collection API rather than Stream API:

```
int firstNull = path.indexOf(null);
if(firstNull>=0 && path.stream().skip(firstNull).anyMatch(Objects::nonNull))
    throw new Exception("Invalid path");
```

Comment: as you have been among the top users in Java-8, would you please put some links about that Java-9 feature? :)

Comment: @Jude Niroshan: Here you go